# Disable swipe / gesture up to down and down to up?

Tags: android, swiperefreshlayout

I am just implemented https://github.com/Trinea/android-auto-scroll-view-pager in `ListView` and I combine with `android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout` .

The case : If I remove `SwipeRefreshLayout` , this work fine. but if I set `SwipeRefreshLayout`, this is lag when I set gesture scrolling UP or DOWN... I thik, I must Disable swipe / gesture up to down and down to up, so how to this?